# Remove carriage returns read from input file in Bash

Tags: bash, git-bash

Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x
parent_folder=$(dirname $PWD)

// read from project-list file and assign to array
mapfile -t arr <project-list.txt

for i in "${arr[@]}"; do
   cd "$parent_folder/$i"
done
```

Issue: `bash: cd: $'/d/workspace/node/notification-service\r': Not a directory`. There is `\r` that is getting added. How to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't remove them from `project-list.txt` for some reason (otherwise this question wouldn't make any sense), remove them while expanding `arr`.

```
for i in "${arr[@]%$'\r'}"; do
  ...
```

Answer (score 3):

You can change your `mapfile` statement to remove `\r` using `tr` first:

```
mapfile -t arr < <(tr -d '\r' < project-list.txt)
```

Afterwards examine array content using:

```
declare -p arr
```

Comment: syntax error near unexpected token `<'

Comment: There is no syntax error if you use it in `bash` shell.

Answer (score 0):

*How to prevent this?*

Depends what you mean by *to prevent*. First of all, I would not put them into project-list.txt. Somewhere must have created this file somehow, and there is rarely a real need to have carriage returns in a file. Prevention would start here.

If for whatever reason this is not possible, you could run the file through `dos2unix`:

```
mapfile -t arr <(dos2unix project-list.txt)
```

or, if git-bash does not support process substitution (I don't have it installed, so I can't try this), you do a

```
dos2unix <project-list.txt >project-list.sanitized
mapfile -t arr <project-list.sanitized
```